# Samsung External HDD drive detected, mounted but not accessible on Ubuntu16.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

It worked perfectly on Windows because I uploaded my documents and bookmarks. And once Ubuntu was installed, it detected the external HDD because it came up on the list of disks. I clicked on the disk, and it said it was mounted and linked to the location. So I clicked on the location link, and there's nothing there.

The hard-drive has over 450GB of data on it, so I know there should be something there.  How can I access the data on the external HDD to import it to Ubuntu.?

Comment: Is the drive/file system damaged or can you still see the files from Windows? In both cases, you should *not* attempt to write anything to the disk, or your data might be irrecoverably destroyed.

Comment: My partner plugged it into his Windows 10 laptop, and all files are present and accessible. For some reason I just can't access them on Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay. Please unplug the disk from your Ubuntu machine. Then run `sudo dmesg --clear`, plug the disk in, check which device/partition file descriptor it gets (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`) by examining the output of `lsblk` and then run `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` (replacing `/dev/sdb1` with what you found out). Please [edit] your question and paste the outputs of those last two commands as well as the output from `dmesg` after trying to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the drive has a NTFS partition on it. Ubuntu can normally read NTFS partitions. A problem arises if the NTFS file system is unclean.

The drive was probably unmounted without properly ejecting it first. Reconnect the drive to the Windows machine, and in an elevated command prompt window, type **chkdsk D:/f** where D: is the correct drive letter. **(Do not use ntfsfix under Ubuntu to do this.)** Then eject the disk properly and reconnect it back into the Ubuntu machine, and it should be fine. Cheers, Al